# LINQ and Storedprocedure

Tags: linq

The interview i faced was "What is the difference between LINQ and Stored procedure?".

I don't know whether it is a vague question or proper one. I answered 
*"In Linq there is a support for Closure so you can refer the value of outer parameter inside the anonymous body,you can't do the same with Stored procedure".*

Just i am requesting you the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure is stored in the database while any "LINQ" queries would be in your code. I think that's the biggest difference.